# How to change a chart's orientation in Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Given the following data and chart:

[image: chart]

Why is the chart displayed from right to left and how do I change it to appear from left to right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Layout tab under Chart Options > Axes > Horizontal Axis > More options:

[image]

Then in the dialog, uncheck `Values in reverse order`:

[image]

(I initially had it the correct way round before checking this option)

Comment: Is this 2013? This is how mine looks like:  http://i.imgur.com/6s9kmVb.png

Comment: @Eran I have excel 2010. See if you can find Horizontal Axis options somewhere? Maybe when you right click on the horizontal axis?

Comment: @Eran I can also access this dialog by right-clicking on the horizontal axis > Format Axis

Comment: They've changed everything in 2k13, I don't understand what's the point

Comment: @Eran Hmm, I just looked over the [docs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/format-your-chart-HA102809711.aspx) and it's apparently under axis options. Could you try looking there?

Comment: Where dear Jesus where? :-( http://i.imgur.com/dAPuCLd.png

Comment: @Eran Spotted! http://i.stack.imgur.com/kslLo.png

Comment: I need to check my eyes

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain what is so wrong so I can make the answer better?